# Taking the Max date from three date columns

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I need to take the max date of three columns by ID: Date Created, Updated Date, and Transaction Date. Below is a simplified version of how the data I refer to looks like and is not representative of the actual data I am working with.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| ID |  Date Created   | Updated Date | Transaction Date |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 12 |   19-APR-19     |     NULL     |     20-APR-19    |
| 68 |   02-Nov-18     |   03-DEC-18  |     02-NOV-18    |
| 12 |   05-MAY-19     |   12-MAY-19  |     12-MAY-19    |
| 72 |   10-SEP-19     |   01-OCT-19  |     25-SEP-19    |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

After retrieving the max of these columns per ID, I should get:

```
+---------------------+
| ID |      Date      | 
+---------------------+
| 68 |   03-DEC-18    |   
| 12 |   12-MAY-19    |     
| 72 |   01-OCT-19    |   
+---------------------+
```

So far, I have tried a variation of the following:

```
   CASE WHEN
      TO_CHAR(ud.updated_date,'MM/DD/YYYY') >= TO_CHAR(NVL(mqp.trans_effective_date,0),'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_CHAR(ud.updated_date,'MM/DD/YYYY') >= TO_CHAR(NVL(mt.date_created,0),'MM/DD/YYYY') THEN TO_CHAR(ud.updated_date,'MM/DD/YYYY')
      WHEN 
      TO_CHAR(mt.transaction_date,'MM/DD/YYYY') >= TO_CHAR(NVL(ud.updated_date,0),'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_CHAR(mt.transaction_date,'MM/DD/YYYY') >= TO_CHAR(NVL(mt.date_created,0),'MM/DD/YYYY') THEN TO_CHAR(mt.transaction_date,'MM/DD/YYYY')
      WHEN
      TO_CHAR(mt.date_created,'MM/DD/YYYY') >= TO_CHAR(NVL(ud.updated_date,0),'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_CHAR(mt.date_created,'MM/DD/YYYY') >= TO_CHAR(NVL(mt.transaction_date,0),'MM/DD/YYYY') THEN TO_CHAR(mt.date_created,'MM/DD/YYYY')
  END Date
```

But this ends in the following error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NLS PARAMETER got DATE
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I have also tried different variations of:

```
  GREATEST(TO_CHAR(mt.date_created,ud.updated_date,mt.transaction_date), 'MM/DD/YYYY') Date
```

But then I get this error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NLS PARAMETER got DATE
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `greatest()`:

```
select id, greatest(updated_date, mqp.trans_effective_date, mt.date_created)
from . . .
```

Assuming all are of type `date` (as implied by your question), you should have no conversion issues.

If you have ids on multiple rows, then use aggregation:

```
select id, greatest(max(updated_date), max(mqp.trans_effective_date), max(mt.date_created))
from . . .
```

Comment: :) Thanks you guys! I was able to simplify by taking out the conversion.

Comment: Hi @forpas, it does. This is part of a much larger query. I have also checked it against other report results and it is matching. Thank you for asking.

Comment: @forpas, as I mentioned above 'Below is a simplified version of how the data I refer to looks like and is not representative of the actual data I am working with.' The above answered my question by not only taking the greatest value I required, but also simplified the selection I was using by taking out the 'TO_CHAR' function. This was causing me to get an error, which I also stated above. I hope this better clarifies why I accepted this particular answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want the max of the greatest of the 3 dates if you group by id:

```
SELECT ID, 
  TO_CHAR(MAX(GREATEST("date_created", "updated_date", "transaction_date")),'MM/DD/YYYY') "Date"
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7e5f6a95ce2e3ad9c73d251bc08ee121).
Results:

```
> ID | Date      
> -: | :---------
> 72 | 10/01/2019
> 68 | 12/03/2018
> 12 | 05/12/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

You have tried correct thing, Just need simple change (first take the greatest date and then convert it to character using `TO_CHAR`):

```
TO_CHAR(GREATEST(mt.date_created,ud.updated_date,mt.transaction_date), 'MM/DD/YYYY') as your_Date
```

Cheers!!